# database query online and offline based system

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am working in an offline system to store the details in my local database, but at day end I have to upload the whole database into the online system of same system. Now, the problem is what happen if there are two or more users use the system at different places and  want to upload their data. then how the online database will distinguish the primary keys value of all the local database. as both online and offline database are replica of each other. I am using mysql as database.